# Why is my Symfony route is not working?

Tags: php, symfony

I made a new Symfony2 bundle and deleted the Acme bundle.

Then I created a new Controller (`MainController.php`):

```
<?php
namespace My\BlogBundle\Controller;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {

        return array();
    }
```

And a simple view: (`Main/index.html.twig`) which only contains a `hello`. My routing.yml is empty. When I run the whole project I get:

```
No route found for "GET /"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »
```

What is wrong here and how to solve it?

Here is my routing debug:

```
\Symfony>php app/console router:debug
[router] Current routes
Name                     Method Pattern
_wdt                     ANY    /_wdt/{token}
_profiler_search         ANY    /_profiler/search
_profiler_purge          ANY    /_profiler/purge
_profiler_info           ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}
_profiler_import         ANY    /_profiler/import
_profiler_export         ANY    /_profiler/export/{token}.txt
_profiler_phpinfo        ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
_profiler_search_results ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
_profiler                ANY    /_profiler/{token}
_profiler_redirect       ANY    /_profiler/
_configurator_home       ANY    /_configurator/
_configurator_step       ANY    /_configurator/step/{index}
_configurator_final      ANY    /_configurator/final
```

I also cleared the cache with no success.

Here is the routes.yml:

```
my_blog:
    resource: "@MyBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

and the routing.yml in `MyBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` is empty.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "index.html.twig" (starts with lowercase)? Also, are you accessing app_dev.php, or app.php? There is a command for debugging routes, I think it was 'app/console routes:debug', something like that. Type 'app/console' alone and find it there. Another thing you can always try is clearing the cache with "rm -r app/cache/*". Oh and show us your routes.yml file.

Comment: I did all of this and updated my post. But It was not successful

Comment: I believe Sf2 has a debug toolbar - anything in that of interest?

Comment: If your `MyBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` file is empty there is no route leading to `/` (as shown in the debug result command)

Comment: The @Route("/", name="index") will handle it or not?

Comment: Yes but not the way you have setup your main routes.yml, I'll write an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way your `routes.yml` is setup, you are requesting the `routing.yml` file from your bundle.

If you want to use annotations to manage the routes in your bundle, you have to write the `routes.yml` the following way:

```
my_blog:
    resource: "@MyBlogBundle/Controller/MainController.php"
    prefix:   /
    type:     annotation
```

And your controller needs to include the `Route` class from the `FrameworkExtraBundle`:

```
<?php
namespace My\BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

This assumes you have installed the `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html#installation).

More information on the route annotation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html

Comment: now I get: "Fatal error: Class 'My\BlogBundle\Controller\Controller' not found in C:\       [...]\Symfony\src\My\BlogBundle\Controller\MainController.php on line 6"

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to add `
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;` in the controller

Comment: ok thank you. this is solved, next problem: "Cannot import resource "C:\[...]\Symfony\src\My\BlogBundle/Controller/MainController.php" from "C:/[...]/Symfony/app/config\routing.yml"."

Comment: No idea if it can work but what if you put `resource: "@MyBlogBundle\\Controller\\MainController.php"`?

Comment: Cannot import resource "@MyBlogBundle\Controller\MainController.php" from "C:/Users/foo/Downloads/Symfony/app/config\routing.yml". Make sure the "MyBlogBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23113/discussion-between-cheesemacfly-and-gurehbgui)

Comment: UPDATE NEEDED: You also need to include the Template service, like this: use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

Answer (score 3):

For others troubleshooting the situation where the router annotations is correctly installed, but the routes aren't working, you may need to install

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could declare your routing for your annotation with:

```
blog_index:
    path: /
    defaults: {_controller:BlogBundle:index}
```

in your BlogBundle/config/routing.yml

and in root, set

```
blog:
    resource: "@BlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

then in your MainController, the annotation should work:

```
..use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

       /**
         * @Route("/", name="blogindex")
         */
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following annotation for the `MainController` class:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
class MainController extends Controller
{
}
```

Comment: did not help, same problem

Answer (score 0):

you'r problem is that you have referenced the routing as yml not annotations, if you want to use annotations you must declare at your front route att the app folder as

```
post:
    resource: "@AcmeBlogBundle/Controller/PostController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

and at the PostController class you define

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    class MainController extends Controller
    {
    }
```

and the function

```
    /**
     * @Route("/add", name="article_add")
     */
     public function add(){
        ...
     }
```

See the referance at the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)